# Angular 1 or Angular 2 for asp.net core mvc?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I would like to learn angular for web projects in asp.net core mvc which version is preferred to learn? Also report any useful links to learn angular with asp.net core mvc crud, thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

For a new project the current angular version 4.0 would be preferred. The official angular site has a [great tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) to get startet.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was documenting on angular 2 i was thinking of knockout or the vuejs limit, what do you think?